# How to show online and offline properly using socketio

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

So far I have been doing some testing on online and offline features using socketio, but I stumble upon a really weird bug. The bug is

User A (Browser A) and User B (Browser B)

When User A open his browser, he will be connected via socketio so does User B.

How to make both of them online, its always one of them is online and the other is not online

I got **socket.request** by using `passport.socketio` module, so every logged in user will be connected via this library

Here's the code
**Serverside**

```
   io.on('connection', function(socket) {

     // This happen whenever user is online.
     User.findById({ _id: socket.request.user._id}, function(err, foundUser) {

      if (err) console.log(err);

      foundUser.socketId = socket.id;
      foundUser.online = true;
      foundUser.save(function(err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        socket.broadcast.emit('connection', 'Online');
      });
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
      User.findById({ _id: socket.request.user._id}, function(err, foundUser) {

        if (err) console.log(err);

        foundUser.online = false;
        foundUser.save(function(err) {
          if (err) console.log(err);
          socket.broadcast.emit('connection', 'Offline');
        });
      });
    }); 
});
```

**ClientSide socket.js**

```
socket.on('connection', function(data) {
  $('#online').html(data);
});

socket.on('disconnect', function() {
  $('#online').html("Offline");
});
```

**ClientSide test.html**

```
<button type="button" id="online" class="btn btn-default"></button>
```

How to show both of them online or offline at the same time?

Whenever User A' refresh --> User B's page is showing that User A is online

while

On User A's page, User B is not online and vice versa

Although both of them are connected via socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are missing two things.

1) An initial state/list of online users, sent to your clients on startup.

2) When there is an online/offline event, send the user who went online/offline to all clients, so clientA notices clientB went online.

---

Edit: Code requested... at least some pseudocode:

PS: I assume "broadcast" sends to all clients.

```
function onlineUsers() {
    var _users;
    User.findAllBy({online:true}, function(err, users){
        _users = JSON.stringify(users);
    });
    return _users;
}

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    // Let clients know currently online on startup.
    socket.emit("receiveOnlineList", onlineUsers());

    // .... your stuff too, but...
    // notice the extra "foundUser" as param, to know who went online.
    // do the same for disconnect.
    socket.broadcast.emit('connection', 'Online', foundUser);

});
```

---

Note that my code will most likely not work, as i don't know IO, nor do i know the libs you are using for persistance.